# Объект класса в качестве поля другого класса. Объявление и определение. С++

Tags: c++, ооп, sfml

Помогите разобраться. В классе GameState есть приватное поле типа Level (level1). У класса Level нет конструктора по умолчанию. Не пойму как мне объявить объект класса Level в заголовочном файле, не указав параметры в конструктор (спрайт, который в параметрах потом берется из картинки, позже в файле .cpp). Ругается, что я объявил Level level1, а не с конструктором с тремя параметрами, но мне то нужно позже проинициализировать, когда текстуры подъедут итп. Эта писанина на SFML C++. Жирным выделил, то как я хочу и где на что.  ругается

```
    class GameState : public State
    {
    public:
        GameState(GameDataRef data);

        void Init();

        void HandleInput();
        void Update(float dt);
        void Draw(float dt);

    private:
        GameDataRef _data;  
        sf::Sprite _tilesetLandscapes;
        Level level1;//здесь объявляю с пустым конструктором, которого нету 
        int gameState;
    };


class Level
{
private:

public:
    Level(int cellsInWidth, int cellsInHeight, sf::Sprite &tileSetForLevel);    
    ~Level();
};



    GameState::GameState(GameDataRef data) : _data(data)
    {

    }

    void GameState::Init()
    {   
        _data->assets.LoadTexture("Tileset_Landscapes", "Assets\\Tileset_lanscapes.png");
        _tilesetLandscapes.setTexture(this->_data->assets.GetTexture("Tileset_Landscapes"));

    level1(4, 3, _tilesetLandscapes); //Здесь хочу инициализировать level1
        level1.draw(_data->window);
    }
```

UPD
В общем сделал все эти текстуры отдельно, подсмотрел в одном видео. Там через умные указатели, рано или поздно надо было все равно нормальный ресурс-менеджер делать без кучи вызовов и дубликатов в памяти ресурсов. Теперь то, что я не мог нормально инициализировать выглядит вот так:

```
GameState::GameState(GameDataRef data) : level1(6, 6), _data(data), _test(sf::Vector2f(120, 50), DUNGEON_WALL)
```

И пока не было этих sfml-ных проблем с белым заполнением спрайта заместо текстуры.

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут

```
GameState::GameState(GameDataRef data) : _data(data)
```

вам нужно вызвать еще и конструктор level с передачей ему соответствующих аргументов:

```
GameState::GameState(GameDataRef data) : _data(data), level1(...,...,...)
```

Зачем у вас вообще отдельная функция `Init()`? Логично ведь инициализировать все в конструкторе :)

Comment: ну если сначала два нуля допустим укажу, а что мне указать в качестве sf::Sprite? Init это из кода чужого дернул просто, пока еще не все вычистил как бы не нужное, скоро уже чужого не будет)

Comment: Ну вы же откуда-то берете третий параметр в `Init`? Понимаете, есть и обходные варианты - например, объявить указатель на `Level`, и в `Init` использовать `new` (и не забыть удалить потом в деструкторе), но любое решение должно быть основано на понимании, что и зачем вы делаете, а не на том, как бы заткнуть этот тупой компилятор, чтоб не ругался...

Comment: @Harry думаю, в этом случае вариант с `new` - не особо-то и обходной, а самый что ни на есть правильный) А если совсем уже хочется боли - можно объявить конструктор без аргументов, а когда появится доступ к данным (которые нужно передать в качестве параметров), сконструировать в этой памяти новый объект через placement new) Но это уже совсем для отчаянных...

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать boost::optional, а для счастивчиков std::optional из C++17.

```
class GameState 
{
...
private:
    ....
    std::optional<Level> level;
    ....
}
GameState::GameState(GameDataRef data) : _data(data)
{
}

void GameState::Init()
{   
    _data->assets.LoadTexture("Tileset_Landscapes", "Assets\\Tileset_lanscapes.png");
    _tilesetLandscapes.setTexture(this->_data->assets.GetTexture("Tileset_Landscapes"));

    level1.emplace(4, 3, _tilesetLandscapes);
    level1->draw(_data->window);
}
```

Память под Level будет выделена вместе с классом, т.е. никакой дополнительной динамической алокации не бедет. Но если обратиться к непроинициализированному level, то будет AV